# angular js scope watch not updating bootstrap badge counter

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am an angular newbie. Fiddling around with $scope.

I have this snippet in my main view:

```
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart  gi-2x"></span><span class="badge">{{ badgeCount }}</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

....
    <div class="container">
           <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
```

home.html gets loaded through ui-view.
Inside home.html, I have

```
    <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-success" ng-model="orderCnt" ng-click="placeOrder(item.desc)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span></button> </td>
    </div>
```

The controller is MainCtrl. 
My controller is:

```
controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, menus) {

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.badgeCount = 0;
  $scope.orderCnt = 0;
  console.log("badgecount=",$scope.badgeCount)
  console.log("ordercnt=",$scope.orderCnt)

  $scope.placeOrder = function(value) {
    $scope.orderCnt ++;
    console.log(value)
    console.log($scope.orderCnt)
    console.log("ng click")
  };

  $scope.$watch('orderCnt', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal + " " + oldVal);
    $scope.badgeCount++;
    console.log("watch")
  },true);
```

---

For any ng-click on placeOrder, I would expect the badgeCount to get updated on the shopping cart icon as well. Its not happening. Do I need to emit/broadcast this since its a different view? I was thinking since both have same controllers, same $scope would be bound. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: code is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/AdYUKQ5VrlQvjgMiAIX8?p=preview

Comment: I think this could be done without using `$watch`, and should be, creating more watchers on page than is necessary will hurt performance.

Comment: ya code works in terms of logic but will not update the shopping cart badge

Comment: Can you fork the plnkr and show your problem? I think it's a problem of different scopes

Answer (score 1):

Is your container `div` a child of the `<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope">`? If not then they will have different scopes. Changes in one will not be seen in another.

Some other points

- you don't need `ng-model` defined on the button, doesn't make sense cause it doesn't get changed.
- why are you watching `orderCnt` in this case? It only changes in `scope.placeOrder` so you can call `$scope.badgeCount++;` in `scope.placeOrder`

EDIT: If you want the view to have the same scope you can place it as a child of the main controller. Also note that you're missing a `>` in your definition of `<a href"#"`

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart  gi-2x"></span><span class="badge">{{ badgeCount }}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. No its not a child. Do i just use a </div> after <div class="container">
           <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>

Comment: See edited post to place `container` as a child of the `MainCtrl`

Comment: thanks. Instead of <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">, can I use <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope"> and then enclose <div class="container">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div> with a closing </div>

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then no, because that won't change its position in the DOM to be nested under the `MainCtrl` and you would just have a rogue `</div>`. Perhaps create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can get a full view of your structure

Comment: I tried placing it as a child. Still no effect on the badge. Maybe its because a bootstrap badge its not updating correctly ?